# Wordpress search Post by POST ID?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my word press query to search post.

```
$args = array('p'=>array('52','62','33','50'),'post_type' => 'job_listing','posts_per_page'=>'-1');
$posts_by_job_type = new WP_Query($args);
```

but i can't find post to like id 52,62,33,50 it return 0 posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array('post__in'=>array('52','62','33','50'),'post_type' => 'job_listing','posts_per_page'=>'-1');
$posts_by_job_type = new WP_Query($args);
```

**Refer Here**

[**Wp Query**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

Comment: it return only one record ID=50 it return only 50 no. record?

Comment: are sure  post type of post with id = `52` is `job_listing` ?

Comment: if the post_name filed into database is null the post is display or not. please help me.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you

Comment: even there is no post title or name it will be displayed as it has an id check url on post edit page. Only getting one record ID=50 means it might not be in loop. after WP_Query($args) use while loop ($posts_by_job_type).